# Undefined flash method in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, undefined, flash-message

I am using Laravel 9, I use flash method to show message but error show in flash method, undefine method 'flash' intelephense(1013)

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
return redirect('/admin');
```

Comment: A quick look at the Laravel documentation for [Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#flash-data) would reveal that it's actually `->session()`, not `->session`: `$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');`

Comment: https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/2216

Answer (score 5):

Simply remove the $request and it will work perfectly fine.

```
session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Wonder why the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#flash-data) have the `$request` on it.

Answer (score 1):

- Check if session is  started.  Add
  `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` into $middleware
  array in `Kernel.php`
- You can check if `$request->session()->all()` works there. (
  Retrieving all session data )

Answer (score 0):

You can check this->Session in Controller it's work.

```
$this->$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
return redirect('/admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, it's just an extension problem. i also have the same problem.
Your program will still run properly. you don't need to do anything. just run your program.

but, if you want to get rid of the error sign you can follow the code like this

```
return redirect('/admin')->with('status', 'Task was successful!');
```